# How do I hide OSGi services so that other bundles can't find them?

Tags: java, javafx, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am developing an application that is build on top of Apache Felix and JavaFX. The application can be extended by 3rd party bundles that implement a specific Interface and make it available to the OSGi Runtime Service Registry.

The problem is that those bundles (or plugins) should not be able to retrieve any of the services that are just used internally by my application. An example would be a PersistenceService that is used to save the processed data. Plugins are (in my application) by definition not allowed to store any data through my service but are allowed to save them through a specific service designed for the plugins only.

I had the idea of using the FindHook Interface offered by OSGi to filter out those requests but that didn't work good. Obviously, to make it work, the bundle needs to me loaded at the very start, eve before my core application gets loaded. I ensured this happens by specifying the start level for this bundle using the `felix.auto.deploy.install.1 = "file\:bundles/de/zerotask/voices-findhook/0.1-SNAPSHOT/voices-findhook-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"`

As far as I understood, the start level of the system bundle will be 1 which means that my bundle should always be loaded right after the system bundle.

Here is my implementation of the FindHook interface:

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;
import org.osgi.framework.hooks.service.FindHook;

/**
 *
 * @author PositiveDown
 */
public class VoicesFindHook implements FindHook {

private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VoicesFindHook.class);

private static final String[] INTERNAL_BUNDLE_TABLE = new String[]{
    "de.zerotask.voices-core-actions",
    "de.zerotask.voices-findhook",
    "de.zerotask.voices-interfaces-persistable",
    "de.zerotask.voices-models",
    "de.zerotask.voices-models-actions",
    "de.zerotask.voices-services-configuration-internal",
    "de.zerotask.voices-services-input-internal",
    "de.zerotask.voices-services-licenses-internal",
    "de.zerotask.voices-services-modelsmanager-internal",
    "de.zerotask.voices-services-persistence-internal",
    "de.zerotask.voices-services-window-internal",
    "de.zerotask.voices-ui-dialogs-about",
    "de.zerotask.voices-ui-dialogs-newprofile",
    "de.zerotask.voices-ui-dockable-listview",
    "de.zerotask.voices-ui-dockable-properties",
    "de.zerotask.voices-ui-layout",
    "de.zerotask.voices-utils-io",
    "de.zerotask.voices-utils-services",
    "de.zerotask.voices-utils-ui"
};

private static final String[] INTERNAL_SERVICES_TABLE = new String[]{
    // model services
    // configuration service
    "de.zerotask.voices.services.configuration.IConfiguration",
    // window service
    "de.zerotask.voices.services.window.IWindowService",
    // persistence services
    "de.zerotask.voices.services.persistence.IPathResolver",
    "de.zerotask.voices.services.persistence.IPersistenceService"
};

private static final Set<String> INTERNAL_BUNDLES = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(INTERNAL_BUNDLE_TABLE));

private static final Set<String> INTERNAL_SERVICES = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(INTERNAL_SERVICES_TABLE));

@Override
public void find(BundleContext context, String name, String filter, boolean allServices, Collection<ServiceReference<?>> references) {
    // only allow the usage of internal interfaces from internal packages
    String symbolicName = context.getBundle().getSymbolicName();
    // debug
    log.debug("Processing Bundle {} and service {}", symbolicName, name);
    // if the service is one of the internal ones, proceed
    if (INTERNAL_SERVICES.contains(name)) {
        // retrieve the bundle id
        log.debug("Service {} is in internal table", name);
        // if the name is not in the internal bundle table, remove all service references
        if (!INTERNAL_BUNDLES.contains(symbolicName)) {
            log.debug("Bundle {} not in internal table => removing service references...", symbolicName);
            // remove them
            references.clear();
        }
    }
}
}
```

The idea is to have a table of ```` internal bundles``` and ````internal services```. Each time a service is looked up, the hook will check if it is an internal service. If this is the case, it will also check if the caller bundle is an internal bundle. If that's not true, the hook will remove all services found from the collection.

I am by far no OSGi expert but this method should work because it is based on the `SymbolicName`s which are unique in each container.

I have tested the above code with two small test bundles. One providing the interface + implementation and the other one consuming it. I changed the hook so it will not return any services for the consumer bundle (to just simply check if it works).

No my problem is, the consumer bundle gets somehow loaded first. I have no idea why. By doing this it basically breaks my loading property set in the properties file. 
I am not sure if this helps but the provider bundle's name starts with an 'y', the consumer one with an 't' and the hook one with an 'v'. 
The funny thing is, Felix is loading them in alphabetically order.

I would really appreciate any help here.

Comment: I guess I would simply say, don't worry about this. Document your services as for internal use by your other bundles and trust that others will not use them. If you create such a wall around your services, you make it brittle against future changes where you must always update the wall.

Comment: That would mean that users need to be self aware that the 3rd party plugins can contain malicious code that may manipulate the state of the application.

Comment: @SirWindfield Isn't that always the case? If you expect people might install malicious code then it's already game over, and just hiding a few services will not protect you.

Comment: Afaik, the OSGi "subsystem" spec is what you need : the isolation of applications in an OSGi container (isolate/restrict capabilities from the subsystems). But as no one a talk about it, I suppose it's an obsolete/not implemented spec (I have never used it personnaly)

Answer (score 3):

Services are implicitly available to every bundle – that is the purpose of services after all.

You can work around this with various hacks like FindHooks etc, but as you have already discovered you are constantly fighting against the true nature of the OSGi Framework and services.

It sounds more like you are creating an isolation system between a kernel and a user space, so that you cannot accidentally pollute the user area with kernel services and *vice versa*. The proper way (IMHO) to achieve this is with a separate OSGi Framework instance for the two areas. It's quite simple to run up a new Framework using the `FrameworkFactory` API. Then you can expose select packages and services from the kernel using the `BundleContext` of the system bundle of the user-area Framework.

However as BJ points out in comments, you may be over-engineering this. What's the worst that can happen if the plugins can see your system services? If those services are well designed then the answer should be "not a lot".

Comment: The worst thing that might happen is the process of deleting the user data processed by the application.  Passing the data id to the persistence service's method "delete"  will do so. Any ideas how I prevent something like this?

Comment: If you can't trust the bundles in your plugins you're majorly screwed. The only quite awful solution is to revert to the Security Manager. I advise not to go that route. It is actually quite simple, if you can't run your bundles then the ONLY solution is to run them in a separate process. Distributed OSGi or Remote Services Admin is then your friend.

Comment: @SirWindfield Make the IDs opaque and difficult to guess.

Comment: @NeilBartlett don't try to achieve security by obscurity.

Comment: @tobias_ What a silly comment. Of course I'm not doing that. I've already said there is no security here. If there are malicious bundles in the framework then you have already lost.

Comment: I fully agree with the answer from Neil. You have to treat all the bundles in the framework as trusted. There is no good way to achieve security against malicious code.

Answer (score -1):

I see two options:

- [ServicePermission](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/ServicePermission.html), this is the standard way;

or

- [ServiceFactory](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/ServiceFactory.html), you decide what bundle can get the real service. Others receive a fake implementation.